# Как сделать экземпляр как атрибут класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Нужно сделать экземпляр Privileges как атрибут класса `Admin()`.

Написал вот такой код:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def describe_user(self):
        print('Name: ' + self.first_name)
        print('Surname: ' + self.last_name)

    def great_user(self):
        full_name = self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
        print('Hello, ' + full_name + '!')

class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, privileges=''):
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        self.privileges = [
            'Allowed advertising messages',
            'Allowed to delete users',
            'Allowed to ban users'
        ]
        for priveleg in self.privileges:
            print(priveleg)

class Admin(User):
    def __init___(self, first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.privileges = Privileges()

admin = Admin('Misha', 'Zhurbiy')

admin.describe_user()
admin.privileges.show_privileges()
```

---

Но в терминале выводится подобное сообщение:

> Name: Misha
> Surname: Zhurbiy
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "...", line 38, in 
> admin.privileges.show_privileges()
> AttributeError: 'Admin' object has no attribute 'privileges'

В чём проблема?

Comment: `class Admin`  `def __init___` <<< лишнее подчёркивание!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Admin(User):
    privileges = Privileges()                          # <----
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
```

Таким образом можно описать атрибут *класса*, а в вашем случае был описан атрибут *экземпляра класса*.

Та ошибка, которая у вас была, была вызвана лишним подчёркиванием в описании конструктора класса: `__init___` вместо `__init__`.

Comment: А почему эта строка должна быть именно сверху? По учебнику, который я читаю она должна быть снизу.

Comment: То что вы называете “должно быть снизу‘ - это атрибут метода.